# Error for formatting Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this code:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Now, I try to format check some String data,

```
final String format = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format("2022-12-07T10:57:23.970Z");
```

I get the error that Cannot format the given Object as a Date. Whats the issue here and how do I resolve it?

Comment: You need to pass in an argument of type `Date`, not a `String`. What would be the point of formatting an already formatted date? In addition, you should actually be using the "new" [Java Date-Time APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/datetime/index.html) instead of the legacy date classes.

Comment: Please clarify what is your purpose. Do you want to change date format of a string? Or do you want to convert string to Date?

Comment: I want to validate if the format is correct for the given string.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It would seem to me that you may have forgot to search before asking? This should be easy to find when you paste the exception message into any decent search engine.

Comment: Your string is in ISO 8601 format. Unless you have special format requirements, the simple way to validate it is `Instant.parse("2022-12-07T10:57:23.970Z")`. In this case (the valid case) it succeeds. Had the string been invalid, it would have thrown a `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code snippet:

1. The `format` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) formats a `Date` object to `String`. Perhaps, you want to use the `parse` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) which will convert a `String` to a `Date` object.
2. The String you passed is not compliant with the pattern you passed. The `Z` in the pattern mandates that a timezone should be passed. A valid example would be `-0700`. An example of this is shown in the javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html); just search with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.